# .htaccess not working on localhost (manjaro)

Tags: .htaccess, visual-studio-code, apache2

I've been spending all afternoon trying to solve this but couldn't by myself.

I've been trying in VSCode to implement an admin area by using .htaccess but the page will load without asking me anything.

I get no error whatsoever, neither do I in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

I modified AutoOverride in httpd.conf as such :

```
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/srv/http"
<Directory "/srv/http">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and uncommented `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Here's my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
AuthName "Page d'administration protégée"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile "/home/badakzz/php/openclassroom/htdocs/sql/blog/admin/.htpasswd"
Require valid-user
```

[image: Here's the VSCode project structure]

I honestly don't know where to search anymore, I'm very new to Linux few people use Manjaro so they don't seem to have "/srv/http" as DocumentRoot (which I tried to copy my VSCode project into but it didn't change anything).

Thanks in advance for helping me in my misery...!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following Solution:

1. Edit the: /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf file
   Change:

   ```
   AllowOverride Option1 Option2 Option3
   ```

to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

2. Save and restart apache:

   sudo systemctl restart httpd
3. Test it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This certainly needs more information, since enabling MultiViews here doesn't appear to make sense?!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30574414)